# PDO Insert statement not working?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to test out a PDO insert statement and for some really weird reason its not inserting the info and not giving me an error message.

I tried running a regular query (with out using prepared statements) and it works.. but this one is not doing any inserts and not giving me an error message.

If anyone can please help me resolve this I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
$msg_table_query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO msg_messaes (sender_id,recipient_id,msg ) VALUES (:sender_id, :recipient_id, :msg");

$msg_table_query->execute([':sender_id' => 3, ':recipient_id' => 4, ':msg' => 'test']);

var_dump($db->errorInfo());
```

Comment: no errors because you're probably not looking for them http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: `:msg")` <= misplaced quote and missing bracket. this is a syntax error which is off-topic. and that checking for errors, would have signaled that.

Comment: hungry ones will post answers below, just you just watch. here `:msg)");` now delete it, I fixed it.

Comment: ok... this question is still up; what now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to close the prepare function.

That's all.

$msg_table_query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO msg_messaes (sender_id,recipient_id,msg ) VALUES (:sender_id, :recipient_id, :msg")");

$msg_table_query->execute([':sender_id' => 3, ':recipient_id' => 4, ':msg' => 'test']);

var_dump($db->errorInfo());